# Ionic innerHTML update

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Trying to update a div that lives within a `component` with `innerHTML`, value depends on user interaction. The data comes in correct by `http` but it only updates when I click into the component, not when `drawerHTML` is updated.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that `drawerHTML` is set from within a cordova plugin of *Google Maps* marker click callback. I believe this is the culprit because it might be running in an asynced callback that sets the value, but seems does not call for an update of the element.

```
marker.addEventListener(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe((data) => {
    this._myProvider.getData(marker.getTitle()).subscribe((data) =>{
          this.drawerHTML = this._prepare(data);
          console.log(this.drawerHTML);
    });
});
```

This is where it's shown:

```
<content-drawer [options]="drawerOptions">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button color="light" clear (click)="showDrawer()">
          showDrawer
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>

  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-content>
    <div [innerHTML]="drawerHTML">

    </div>
    <button ion-button round small (click)="hideDrawer()">Close</button>
  </ion-content>
</content-drawer>
```

`content-drawer` setup as a ionic / angular component in a separate file
with `content-drawer.html` as:

```
<ion-content>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</ion-content>
```

and the above code projected from my home into `ng-content`.
Seems I have to make `content-drawer` update itself manually since data is not updated at runtime? The DOM tree has to be updated?

The content-drawer is based on [this implementation](https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-a-sliding-drawer-component-for-ionic-2/).

Comment: The [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) might come in handy in your case :)

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it with `[innerHTML]="drawerHTML | async"` but it returns `InvalidPipeArgument for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`

Comment: Ah yeah, you might have to refactor your code a little: [As you can see in the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe#input-value) the async pipe expects an Observable or a Promise as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ChangeDetectorRef.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
```

Inject and instantiate it

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef:ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

Write your code like this.

```
marker.addEventListener(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe((data) => {
    this._myProvider.getData(marker.getTitle()).subscribe((data) =>{
          this.drawerHTML = this._prepare(data);
          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    });
});
```

This may solve your problem.[Triggering change detection manually in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-change-detection-manually-in-angular)